# garbage output using cat

Tags: bash, while-loop

I have a file that contains paths to files, and I want to write to a new file all the paths and the content of the files they lead to.

my script:

```
rm -f answer.txt
touch answer.txt
while IFS= read -r path; do
    echo $path >>answer.txt # path
    cat $path >>answer.txt  # content
    printf '\n--------\n' >> answer.txt
done < ./files_paths.txt #the file that contains the paths
```

(the paths file looks like this)

```
    /atc/ld.so.cache
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
    ... more paths
```

(I want the answer.txt to look like)

```
/atc/ld.so.cache #path
1HAajfj # content
------
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
asd5446
------
...
```

My problem is that in the beginning of the txt file, I have tons of lines of garbage.
After all the garbage, I get what I want.

[start of file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Imkg.png)

[after all the garbage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/We3JV.png)

Comment: Well you're trying to grab the content of a library file, which is going to cause all that garbage. Everything on my end seems to work fine, so I think it's just the type of files you are grabbing thats the issue

Comment: I'm completely sure that the content of `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6` is not `asd5446`. I'm pretty sure you are not getting garbage, but what you said you want. Everything looks fine, except that your expectation is wrong.

Comment: Maybe use the `strings` command and/or `grep -a` to filter out the relevant text from your binary files.